# Error on binding table value to Combobox - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox which should bind the data dynamically from the database .

The source of the combobox is a observable collection.

Steps I followed:

1. Declared a combobox :

   ```
   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding populatecombobox.modeltogetusername }" Width="155" Margin="18,15,618,0"/>
   ```
2. Created a class to get the data from the database :

   ```
   public class populatetab2combobox
   {
       public ObservableCollection<comboboxdata> modeltogetusername { get; set; }

       public void getdatausinglinq()
       {
           using (Operations_Productivity_ToolEntities context = new Operations_Productivity_ToolEntities())
           {
               var a1 = from t1 in context.Test_ImportedAuditdata
                        select t1;

               if (modeltogetusername == null)
                   modeltogetusername = new ObservableCollection<comboboxdata>();

               foreach (var a in a1.GroupBy(x => x.username).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()))
               {
                   modeltogetusername.Add(new comboboxdata
                   {
                    username = a.username
                   });

               }
           }

       }

   }
   ```
3. Instantiating the above mentioned class in viewmodel

   ```
   public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {
   private populatetab2combobox _populatecombobox = new populatetab2combobox();

   public populatetab2combobox populatecombobox {
       get {
           return _populatecombobox;
       }
       set {
           if (value != _populatecombobox) {
               _populatecombobox = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("populatecombobox");
           }
       }
   }
   public ViewModel() {
       _populatecombobox.getdatausinglinq();
   }
   ```

   }

The expected output is :

```
Ren1
Ren2
```

The actual output is

```
Namespace.Model.comboxdata
Namespace.Model.comboxdata
```

Comment: You need to set the SelectedValuePath and DisplayMemberPath on your combobox xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the output of the ToString() method and you are binding to instances of comboboxdata class and not the username inside of it.

You have 2 options.
First you can change your xaml to this notice how we bind to the property in the item template.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding populatecombobox.modeltogetusername }" Width="155" Margin="18,15,618,0">
  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding username}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Second you can override the ToString() method on comboboxdata to return the username